# CS 2 Servers Get Status Any Method (Api / Website / NodeJS Package)

Tags: node.js, steam, steam-web-api, steamworks-api, steambot

can we learn the name of a player on a server in CS 2, how long he played and his score, through the Steam API or any other method?
I need code that prints these to the console via NodeJS

Example: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sourcequery ( Working CS:GO )

Code Example:

`let ip = "Server İp Adress", port = 27015;`
`// console.log(servername);`
`// console.log(servermap);`
`// console.log(serverplayernumber);`
`// console.log(servermaxplayernumber);`
`// console.log(serverplayersname);`
`// console.log(serverplayersscore);`
`// console.log(serverplayerstime);`